# Removing Softmax from last layer yields a lot better results

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, nlp, softmax

I was solving an nlp task, of converting English sentences to German in Keras. But the model was not learning... But as soon as I removed the softmax from the last layer, it started working! Is this a bug in Keras, or it has to do with something else?

```
optimizer = Adam()
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=True, reduction='none')

def loss_function(real, pred):
  mask = tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.equal(real, 0))
  loss_ = loss_object(real, pred)

  mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=loss_.dtype)
  loss_ *= mask

  return tf.reduce_mean(loss_)

EPOCHS = 20
batch_size = 64

batch_per_epoch = int(train_x1.shape[0] / batch_size)

embed_dim = 256
units = 1024
attention_units = 10

encoder_embed = Embedding(english_vocab_size, embed_dim)
decoder_embed = Embedding(german_vocab_size, embed_dim)

encoder = GRU(units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
decoder = GRU(units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')

dense = Dense(german_vocab_size)

attention1 = Dense(attention_units)
attention2 = Dense(attention_units)
attention3 = Dense(1)

def train_step(english_input, german_target):
    loss = 0
    
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      enc_output, enc_hidden = encoder(encoder_embed(english_input))

      dec_hidden = enc_hidden

      dec_input = tf.expand_dims([german_tokenizer.word_index['startseq']] * batch_size, 1)

      for i in range(1, german_target.shape[1]):
        attention_weights = attention1(enc_output) + attention2(tf.expand_dims(dec_hidden, axis=1))
        attention_weights = tanh(attention_weights)
        attention_weights = attention3(attention_weights)
        attention_weights = Softmax(axis=1)(attention_weights)

        Context_Vector = tf.reduce_sum(enc_output * attention_weights, axis=1)
        Context_Vector = tf.expand_dims(Context_Vector, axis = 1)

        x = decoder_embed(dec_input)

        x = Concatenate(axis=-1)([x, Context_Vector])

        dec_output, dec_hidden = decoder(x)

        output = tf.reshape(dec_output, (-1, dec_output.shape[2]))

        prediction = dense(output)

        loss += loss_function(german_target[:, i], prediction)

        dec_input = tf.expand_dims(german_target[:, i], 1)

    batch_loss = (loss / int(german_target.shape[1]))

    variables = encoder_embed.trainable_variables + decoder_embed.trainable_variables + encoder.trainable_variables + decoder.trainable_variables + dense.trainable_variables + attention1.trainable_variables + attention2.trainable_variables + attention3.trainable_variables

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, variables)

    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))

    return batch_loss
```

### Code Summary

The code just take the English sentence and German Sentence as input (It takes German sentence as input to implement Teacher-Forcing Method), and predicts the translated German sentence.
The loss function is `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy`, but it subtracts the loss of the `0`. For example, lets say, we have a sentence, that is : '*StartSeq This is Stackoverflow 0 0 0 0 0 EndSeq*' (The sentence also has a zero padding to make all the input sentences of the same length). Now, we would calculate loss for every word but not for the 0's. Doing this makes the model better.
**Note - this model implementation implements Bahdanau Attention**

### Question

When I apply softmax on the predicted probabilities by the last layer, the model doesn't learns anything. But it learns properly without softmax in the last layer. Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you show a code snippet with what you acutally did? My guess is that you used `CategorialCrossentropy` loss. You can save some computation when you do the softmax and crossentropy together, this why by default, the loss function expects the logits before softmaxing.

Comment: @Jindřich I have edited the post to include everything you are asking for

Comment: This is exactly what from_logits=True in your loss does, if you set this to True, you need to provide logits, not probabilities. So your  result is not surprising at all.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Ohh, thanks for solving the problem!